# Two observable with dependency

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern, observable

I need to have 2 observable : 1 (O1) who has as observers object A and the other 1 (O2) who has as observers object B and A. Objects B and A are different type of objects. 
How should I implement it to do 2 observable, one with a list of A and one with a list of A and B; or to do O1 with a list of A and O2 with list of B and reference to O1? Or should I put all, list with A and list with B, in just one observable? How to make it to respect observer pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

> How i should implement it to do 2 observable one with list of A and one with list of A and B, or to do O1 with list of A and O2 with list of B and reference to O1, or I should put all, list with A and list with B, in just one observable ?

If A and B are your Observers, then the pattern allows O1 and O2 to have a list of `Observer` (the aggregation shown by the diamond in UML in the pattern). The `Observer` interface is a kind of disguise for A and B. O1 and O2 see them as the same type (Observer) rather than A and B. Since all Observers implement the `notify()` method, then O1 and O2 can always call that on objects with a reference of type `Observer`.

Here's a diagram of the Observer pattern with the classes you suggest:

[image: Observer pattern]